# Spring WebClient content type application/javascript not supported

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webclient

How can I customize a *Spring WebClient* instance, to accept `content-type: application/javascript` and deserialize the JSON response body?

I've implemented a [simple example](https://github.com/ehayik/coindesk-client) using [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-webclient), which consumes the [CoinDesk API endpoint](https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json) to get the Bitcoin Price Index (BPI) in real-time.

I [reproduced the error](https://github.com/ehayik/coindesk-client/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/ehayik/coindesk/btc/BitcoinPriceIndexClientTests.java) stubbing the endpoint with WireMock.

The endpoint response body content is JSON, however, its headers include `content-type: application/javascript`, as a result the *WebClient* throws the exception below:

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException at WebClientResponseException.java:342
        Caused by: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException at BodyExtractors.java:206
```

[image]

This is the entire stacktrace:

```
200 OK from GET http://localhost:44027/bpi/currentprice.json
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException: 200 OK from GET http://localhost:44027/bpi/currentprice.json
    at app//org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:342)
    at app//org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.lambda$createException$1(DefaultClientResponse.java:213)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorReturn$ReturnSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorReturn.java:199)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onError(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:156)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onError(FluxOnAssembly.java:544)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:142)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onError(FluxContextWrite.java:121)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:340)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxFilterFuseable.java:382)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onError(MonoCollect.java:135)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:134)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:134)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
    at app//reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.startReceiver(FluxReceive.java:191)
    at app//reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.subscribe(FluxReceive.java:148)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.InternalFluxOperator.subscribe(InternalFluxOperator.java:62)
    at app//reactor.netty.ByteBufFlux.subscribe(ByteBufFlux.java:340)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onError(FluxOnAssembly.java:544)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onError(FluxConcatArray.java:207)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxError.subscribe(FluxError.java:43)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8671)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatArray.java:258)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onComplete(MonoIgnoreElements.java:89)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxTakeWhile$TakeWhileSubscriber.onComplete(FluxTakeWhile.java:122)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxTakeWhile$TakeWhileSubscriber.onNext(FluxTakeWhile.java:96)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
    at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)
    at app//reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:379)
    at app//reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:411)
    at app//reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:734)
    at app//reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:113)
    at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at app//io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at app//io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at app//io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
    at app//io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:333)
    at app//io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:454)
    at app//io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
    at app//io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at app//io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at app//io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at app//io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:800)
    at app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:499)
    at app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:397)
    at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at app//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base@17/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:139)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1734)
        at org.springframework.web.service.invoker.HttpServiceMethod$ResponseFunction.execute(HttpServiceMethod.java:301)
        at org.springframework.web.service.invoker.HttpServiceMethod.invoke(HttpServiceMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.service.invoker.HttpServiceProxyFactory$HttpServiceMethodInterceptor.invoke(HttpServiceProxyFactory.java:278)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218)
        at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy73.getPriceIndexOnRealTime(Unknown Source)
        at com.github.ehayik.coindesk.BitcoinPriceIndexClientTests.givenCurrentPriceRequestWhenExchangeThenCorrect(BitcoinPriceIndexClientTests.java:35)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
        at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
        at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
        at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'application/javascript' not supported for bodyType=com.github.ehayik.coindesk.BitcoinCurrentPrice
    at app//org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.lambda$readWithMessageReaders$12(BodyExtractors.java:206)
    Suppressed: The stacktrace has been enhanced by Reactor, refer to additional information below: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Body from GET http://localhost:44027/bpi/currentprice.json [DefaultClientResponse]
Original Stack Trace:
        at app//org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.lambda$readWithMessageReaders$12(BodyExtractors.java:206)
        at java.base@17/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
        at app//org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.readWithMessageReaders(BodyExtractors.java:202)
        at app//org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.lambda$toMono$2(BodyExtractors.java:84)
        at app//org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.body(DefaultClientResponse.java:134)
        at app//org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.bodyToMono(DefaultClientResponse.java:154)
        at app//org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec.lambda$bodyToMono$2(DefaultWebClient.java:597)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:132)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:503)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:854)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:250)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2545)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.request(FluxContextWrite.java:136)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onSubscribeInner(MonoFlatMapMany.java:150)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMapMany.java:245)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxContextWrite.java:101)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust.subscribe(FluxJust.java:68)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8671)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:195)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxRetryWhen.java:174)
        at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:172)
        at app//reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpIOHandlerObserver.onStateChange(HttpClientConnect.java:435)
        at app//reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onStateChange(ReactorNetty.java:710)
        at app//reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onStateChange(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:195)
        at app//reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnection.onStateChange(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:456)
        at app//reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:647)
        at app//reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:113)
        at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
        at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at app//io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
        at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
        at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at app//io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
        at app//io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
        at app//io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:333)
        at app//io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:454)
        at app//io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
        at app//io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
        at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
        at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at app//io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
        at app//io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at app//io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at app//io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:800)
        at app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:499)
        at app//io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:397)
        at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at app//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base@17/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

This is the declarative client implementation:

```java
@HttpExchange(url = "/bpi")
public interface BitcoinPriceIndexClient {

    @GetExchange(value = "/currentprice.json")
    Mono<BitcoinCurrentPrice> getPriceIndexOnRealTime();
}

@Setter
public class BitcoinCurrentPrice {

    private BitcoinPriceIndex bpi;

    public List<Price> getPrices() {
        return List.of(bpi.usdPrice, bpi.eurPrice, bpi.gbpPrice);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @JsonRootName(value = "bpi")
    public static class BitcoinPriceIndex {

        @JsonProperty("USD")
        private Price usdPrice;

        @JsonProperty("GBP")
        private Price gbpPrice;

        @JsonProperty("EUR")
        private Price eurPrice;
    }

    @Data
    @Accessors(chain = true)
    public static class Price {

        private String code;

        @JsonProperty("rate_float")
        private Double rate;
    }
}
```

This is the client's proxy creation:

```java
@Bean  
BitcoinPriceIndexClient bitcoinPriceIndexClient(WebClient.Builder builder, @Value("${bpi-client.url}") String url) {  
    var webClient = builder.baseUrl(url).build();  
  
    var httpServiceProxyFactory =  
            HttpServiceProxyFactory.builder(forClient(webClient)).build();  
  
    return httpServiceProxyFactory.createClient(BitcoinPriceIndexClient.class);  
}
```

Comment: Please post the entire stacktrace. Right now you have only posted a fragment in the middle of the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `WebClient` doesn't have codec for `application/javascript`. You would need to register additional codec for this `Content-Type`

```
var APPLICATION_JAVASCRIPT = new MediaType("application", "javascript");

WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .exchangeStrategies(
                ExchangeStrategies.builder()
                        .codecs(configurer ->
                                // register codec for media type application/javascript
                                configurer.customCodecs().registerWithDefaultConfig(
                                        new Jackson2JsonDecoder(objectMapper, APPLICATION_JAVASCRIPT)
                                )
                        )
                        .build()
        )
        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I already worked on spring web-client and we almost connects with end-points which serves data in form of JSON your response also looks like a JSON response so you can try configuring `application/json`.